# Set texture in effect file

Tags: c#, directx, mdx, hlsl, pixel-shader

I need to pass texture in shader file, but it is giving me error "Invalid call". Please help to tell where i am doing wrong ?
Follow is code which is i have written. I am able to set all the parameter except Texture.

```
float   progress;       
float4 colBack;
float reverse; 

sampler input : register(s0); 
sampler Texture2 : register(s1);

//Code to get the parameterhandle
 progressHandle = transitionEffect.GetParameter(null, "progress"));
 reverseHandle= transitionEffect.GetParameter(null, "Reverse"));
Texture2Handle= transitionEffect.GetParameter(null, "Texture2"));
//Code to set the value
 transitionEffect.SetValue(progressHandle, progress);

 transitionEffect.SetValue(reverseHandle, Reverse);
transitionEffect.SetValue(Texture2Handle, smapleTexture);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow please use the  `{}` toolbox button to represent your coding.

Comment: Managed DirectX is no longer supported by Microsoft.  I'd strongly recommend using XNA or SlimDX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, this may be use for someone else for the same problem.

I need to make Texture structure to pass the texture in shader file. code as follow.

```
texture Texture;
sampler Texture2 = sampler_state
{
    texture = <Texture>;
    magfilter = LINEAR;
    minfilter = LINEAR;
    mipfilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU = mirror;
    AddressV = mirror;
};
```